# jQuery scroll method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I have a div, which is filling the whole screen with a video and some other content, under that div i have another div. But that one i have hidden. The reason for that is because i dont want people manually to scroll to the other div.

So i've made a small jQuery snippet to make the other div show, and scroll to that. But it wont work, can anyone help me with this?

Heres my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#exploreBtn').on('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#content').fadeIn(500);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

"#exploreBtn" is a button ive created on the div filling the screen.

"#content" is the div i have hidden, and want to show and scroll to.

Comment: "Isn't working" is not a very good description. Does the click handler fire, does the element fade in, does the page reload? Be more specific.

Comment: @adeneo The click handler does fire indeed, the #content fades in aswell, but the scrolling just doesnt work.

Comment: Actually, seems to be working **http://jsfiddle.net/89UdF/1/**

Comment: Wow thanks man :D but how does it come you need to set the position to absolute?

Comment: I just did that to make it easy to position the elements, there are ways to position the elements using relative positioning that should work exactly the same way ?

Comment: Oo, how would i do that then? because now i want, when i'm at the scroll position of "#content" i want to hide the first page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52335/discussion-between-user2989034-and-adeneo)

Comment: @adeneo When i change the top to 0 again, and change the display property to none of the 'fitScreen', the transition is really ugly and it slides me down abit aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/89UdF/11/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#exploreBtn').on('click', function() {

    $('#content').fadeIn(500);
    console.log($("#content").offset().top)
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top

    }, 1000);
     $('#page1').hide();
    $('#content').css('top',0); 
       $(document).scrollTop(0);
});
```

});